# Create Argo CD application not from repo but from CRD

Tags: go, kubernetes, argocd

I want to create ArgoCD Application(app#1) that will contain an operator (for instance, Postgres operator) and I want to create another ArcoCD Application(app#2) but this time this application(app#2) should be the instance of the Postgres DB itself and be managed by its operator that is installed with app#1. Is it possible using Argocd source code to create this app#2 with CRD of Postgres DB(this CRD is likely part of helm chart of Postgres operator)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if I got your question right, however you can use the "apps of apps" pattern to have one ArgoCD application, install several other applications on your behalf. You can read the official docs here: https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/cluster-bootstrapping/